# Can "that is" be elided in defining attributive clauses?

Tags: clauses, time, adverbial-phrases

> With **the introduction of computed tomography(CT) followed by other 
>   digital diagnostic imaging modalities** in the 1970's,and the increasing
>   use of computers in  clinical applications , the American College of
>   Radiology(ACR) and the National Electrical  Manufacturers
>   Association(NEMA) recognized the emerging need for a standard method
>   for transferring images and associated information between devices
>   manufactured by various vendors.

I think that the words 'that is', are elided from the bold section like this:

- *the introduction of computed tomography (CT) **that is** followed by other digital diagnostic imaging modalities*

And the sentence means that CT was introduced in 1970's, and the other modalities followed CT.

Is it right?

---

Now I'm getting a little confusion about the word '**followed by**'.
I thought it should be '**Be followed by**'.And that is what my learned before.

But I searched 'follow by' on Google.Then I found this sentence :

"To follow by faith alone is to follow blindly." -Benjamin Franklin

So the word 'follow by' here is a ... fixed phrase?It's not a ... passive voice?

And more importantly, what comes first ?

Comment: In what you have provided of the sentence I don't see anyplace where *that is* might have been elided.  Where do you think "that is" might belong?

Comment: I don't see a place for a 'that is' either. Can you edit the question to provide more context, or to indicate at least where you think it ought to belong.

Comment: You certainly **can** make a sentence that reads: *The introduction of computed tomography that is followed by other diagnostic modalities resulted in the ACR and The NEMA recognizing the emerging need for ...*  HOWEVER, you can't start that sentence with ***With***.  The sentence as written does not have ***that is*** elided.

Comment: I think there's just a comma missing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are correct that "followed by" is passive. Not a fixed phrase.

If anything was "elided" after (CT), I suggest it was a *comma*.

. . . (CT)**,** followed by. . .

You could insert **which was**" (NOT *that is*) but it's completely optional—the comma alone would be enough. So I would not say *which was* was elided.

I hope this is simpler for you to understand.

Comment: Hey, that's what I said ;)

Comment: Oh yeah. Didn't see that. Anyway, we're both right. Upvoting your comment.

Answer (score 0):

> > With **the introduction of computed tomography(CT) followed by other 
> >     digital diagnostic imaging modalities** in the 1970's,and the increasing
> >     use of computers in  clinical applications , the American College of
> >     Radiology(ACR) and the National Electrical  Manufacturers
> >     Association(NEMA) recognized the emerging need for a standard method
> >     for transferring images and associated information between devices
> >     manufactured by various vendors.
>
> I think that the words 'that is', are elided from the bold section like this:
>
> - *the introduction of computed tomography (CT) **that is** followed by other digital diagnostic imaging modalities*

You cannot add *that is* to this clause. Otherwise, you will have two finite verbs in the sentence, making it ungrammatical.

Do you understand the structure? Apparently not, if you think *that is* can be added to it. This is one sentence with one independent clause; the independent clause has the finite verb (**recognized**) and may stand on its own:

*the American College of Radiology (ACR) and the National Electrical Manufacturers Association (NEMA) **recognized** the emerging need for a standard method for transferring images and associated information between devices manufactured by various vendors.*

The portion that comes before is two nonfinite clauses separated by a comma:

*With the introduction of computed tomography (CT) followed by other digital diagnostic imaging modalities in the 1970's, and the increasing use of computers in clinical applications,*

Notice that there is no other finite verb in the entire sentence, including the introductory portion; that is the way it should be in a single sentence.

> And the sentence means that CT was introduced in 1970's, and the other modalities followed CT.
>
> Is it right?

That is probably what the sentence means. Although *in the 1970's* could possibly modify only the clause that comes right before it (*followed by other digital diagnostic imaging modalities*), meaning that CT was introduced earlier than the 1970's.

---

> Now I'm getting a little confusion about the word '**followed by**'.
>   I thought it should be '**Be followed by**'.And that is what my learned before.
>
> But I searched 'follow by' on Google.Then I found this sentence :
>
> "To follow by faith alone is to follow blindly." -Benjamin Franklin
>
> So the word 'follow by' here is a ... fixed phrase?It's not a ... passive voice?

**followed by** is not a fixed phrase. It is a participle (*followed*) plus a preposition (*by*). This combination may be used often, but that does not make it a "fixed phrase" anymore than **sent by** is a fixed phrase.

Yes, *followed* is in the passive voice. For example, *I was followed by John* (compare *I was sent by John*.)

> And more importantly, what comes first ?

I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: Thanks for your long answer.It seems a little hard for me,I will read it for several times to understand it.And is the word 'follow by' similar to 'followed by'?